# Font awesome background color is overflown

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-4

I want to set background color for a fontawesome icon :

```
.vert {
      background: springgreen;
    }
...
return '<i class="fa fa-circle-thin vert"></i>';
```

At runtime I get this :

[image]

So how to fill just the interior of the circle ?

Comment: which version of font-awesome are you using.

Comment: Now it is version `5.8.1`

Comment: check this for answer your question: http://jsfiddle.net/je3zxr9k/

Comment: even if you are using version 5 still color property should work as I stated in the answer.

Comment: I tried but does not work ; I m guessing there is smthg interacting with Bootstrap !

Comment: if your changing version the fa should change to far in icon tag. and then try changing its color

Comment: and it doesn't have anything with bootstrap I have an example of using both at the same time you can take a look in answer.

Comment: your answer is not what I m expecting : it just colors the border.

Comment: ok then you have to use solid icon and set border to it

Comment: what is a solid icon ?

Comment: @pheromix you create a solid icon using `fas` and  `fa-circle` as per the answers.

Comment: you can set `font-weight: bold` in the `i` element and use `color` instead of `background-color`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [stacked icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked).

```css
.vert {
  color: springgreen;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all.css">


<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fas fa-circle vert fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="far fa-circle  fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>
```

**Using Layers in Font Awesome 5**

> This feature requires that you use SVG + JS version of Font Awesome 5.

```css
.vert {
  color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js" data-search-pseudo-elements></script>

<div class="fa-4x">
  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw">
    <i class="fas fa-circle vert" ></i>
    <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## font-awesome V5

*This example describes exactly the version you are using.*

```css
.vert {
color: springgreen;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="fa-stack">
  <i class="fas fa-circle vert fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="far fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>
```

**Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/calumchilds/pen/boLwVb) to describe your concern "Something wrong because interacting with bootstrap".**

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colour of the font-awesome icon by using `color: springgreen;`

In addition you will want to use a solid icon such as this https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle?style=solid

```
.vert {
      color: springgreen;
    }
...
return '<i class="fas fa-circle vert"></i>';
```

Comment: @pheromix that is not a problem. You can use https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/circle if you are still using version 4. Just remember to use `fa` instead of `fas` if you are using version 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fill the entire icon with spring green. Then use Border-radius. 
Example:-

```
.vert {
      color: springgreen;
    }
```

Or if you want to color only on the border. You can use the color property as depicted in the above answers.